# structure of python numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to ask a completely new question regarding [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12736278/117700).

The code in the link above returns a numpy array for `open` and `close`:

```
open = np.array([q.open for q in quotes]).astype(np.float)
close = np.array([q.close for q in quotes]).astype(np.float)
```

As per [Dan's help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12736914/117700), `quotes` returns:

> In your case you are using asobject=True so the format you get is
>   date, year, month, day, d, open, close, high, low, volume,
>   adjusted_close.

Therefore, open and close must be elements `[5]` and `[6]` of `quotes`.

```
>>> open
array([[ 28.12235692,  28.32908451,  28.482779  , ...,  84.8198783 ,
         84.1401    ,  84.64308037],
       [ 22.49848073,  22.66286426,  22.91112016, ...,  63.66703704,
         64.57105722,  64.12120097]])
```

and:

```
>>> close
array([[ 28.5 ,  28.53,  29.23, ...,  83.8 ,  84.99,  83.82],
       [ 22.91,  22.71,  23.53, ...,  63.52,  64.78,  63.92]])
>>>
```

I do not understand exacty what `open` and `close` represent.

Is each element of open and close all the prices for that specific stock?

Can you please help me to understand exactly what do open and close contain? **Are they just lists of lists of prices per symbol per day?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quotes` is a list which contains stock information per symbol:

```
In [43]: len(quotes)
Out[43]: 61

In [44]: len(symbols)
Out[44]: 61

In [45]: symbols
Out[45]: 
array(['COP', 'AXP', 'RTN', 'BA', 'AAPL', 'PEP', 'NAV', 'GSK', 'MSFT',
       'KMB', 'R', 'SAP', 'GS', 'CL', 'WAG', 'WMT', 'GE', 'SNE', 'PFE',
       'AMZN', 'MAR', 'NVS', 'KO', 'MMM', 'CMCSA', 'SNY', 'IBM', 'CVX',
       'WFC', 'DD', 'CVS', 'TOT', 'CAT', 'CAJ', 'BAC', 'AIG', 'TWX', 'HD',
       'TXN', 'KFT', 'VLO', 'NWS', 'F', 'CVC', 'TM', 'PG', 'LMT', 'K',
       'HMC', 'GD', 'HPQ', 'DELL', 'MTU', 'XRX', 'YHOO', 'XOM', 'JPM',
       'MCD', 'CSCO', 'NOC', 'UN'], 
      dtype='|S17')
```

For example the first element in `quotes` is for the 'COP' symbol and contains an array of values by date:

```
In [49]: symbols[0]
Out[49]: 'COP'

In [50]: quotes[0].open
Out[50]: 
array([ 13.81001419,  14.01678947,  14.01500099, ...,  56.77238579,
        56.82699428,  56.89080408])

In [51]: quotes[0].date
Out[51]: 
array([2003-01-02, 2003-01-03, 2003-01-06, ..., 2007-12-27, 2007-12-28,
       2007-12-31], dtype=object)
```

Comment: thank you daniel! i got it to work. do you have a few moments to describe exactly what is affinity propogation? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_stock_market.html

Comment: here's the additional q i asked, thanks again! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752480/practical-applications-for-affinity-propagation

Comment: ask your question on some of the machine learning q&a sites

Comment: thanks! can you recommend one?

Comment: can you please recommend a machine learning q and a site?